# Building Fabric network, crypto is not existed in /hyperledger/fabric/peer/ path

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following this tutorial [Build Your First Network](http:///hyperledger/fabric/peer/) to build my first fabric network. After executing `./byfn.sh -m up`, everything looks fine. But When I check environment variables, it mentioned `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`
. But this `crypto` does not exist in `/hyperledger/fabric/peer/` path. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are checking it inside the cli container. Note that a volume mapping between the container named "cli" and your host machine is defined under the file docker-compose-cli.yaml, you can have a look here for the information https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/first-network/docker-compose-cli.yaml#L83. When you issue a command `docker exec -it cli bash` to enter the container named cli, you should be able to find the path.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that there is no folder as **crypto** in the **/hyperledger/fabric/peer/** assuming that you were seeking in the peer of org1 container (e.g. `docker exec -it peer0.org1.example.com`) or other peer containers.

The reason is due to the fact that Environment variables are set in the **cli** container and its uses **fabric-tools** image not **fabric-peer**
 image while orchestration. This setup is seen only in **first network** of fabric samples. While the **cli** makes install, instantiate, query, etc. commands it changes the Environment variables to act as peer before sending those commands.

So, **crypto** material will be in the **cli** container (`docker exec -it cli bash`). You can see the volume mapping of containers and specifically **cli** container for which container the **crypto material** is mapped in ***dockercompose-cli.yaml***, ***base/docker-compose-base.yaml*** and ***base/peer-base.yaml*** files.

***NOTE***:
"first network" or "Build Your First Network" is for only testing and learning purposes not for production.

**References**:
[1] : Building Your First Network (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html?highlight=fabric-tools)